# Bootstrap 3 Column Reordering On Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how easilly achieve this layout with Bootstrap 3.

[image: Bootstrap 3 Layout desired]

Comment: Use media-queries and custom css.

Comment: can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that layout using **bootstrap 3** pretty easy, you just have to arrange your columns in a proper order. The **orange~red** block I believe its a **sidebar**, and the other two blocks have the same width (seems bound to the same container), and I think there you have your **content**.

So, put the **sidebar** **block**, in a container with the desired width from the bootstrap grid, like `col-md-4`, and the **content block** in a container say `col-md-8`; add to both these containers `col-xs-12` class(will add 100% width on 768px and bellow), we'll need it because we're gonna use `pull-left/right`(float rule) class to swap them around.

Check out the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpe17dz3/1/)** and bellow the markup/css used

The markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row cf'>
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right'>
            <div class='orange'>One good lookin sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-8 col-xs-12 pull-left'>
            <div class='content-entry orchid'>
                Some content here
            </div>
             <div class='content-entry cyan'>
                And some other content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.orange{
    background: orange;
}
.orchid{
    background: orchid;
}
.cyan{
    background: cyan;
}
```

**Note: if you want that sidebar to expand it's height to the height of the other 2 blocks combined, that's a different story, but this should get you started.

**UPDATE 2**

OK since you have a layout a bit tricky on mobile, I guess your safest bet would be to make the **sidebar** `absolute` positioned, and on mobile(**bellow and 767px**), switch it to static position, to make em fall into a natural flow. There are some more other methods out there like flexbox, or maybe some fancy table tricks, but this one should get you going.

Check out the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpe17dz3/2/)**, and the changed markup/css bellow:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row content-wrapper'>
        <div class='col-sm-8 col-xs-12'>
            <div class='content-entry orchid'>
                Some content here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sidebar-wrapper'>
            <div class='orange'>One good lookin sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-8 col-xs-12'>
            <div class='content-entry cyan'>
                And some other content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.orange{
    background: orange;
}
.orchid{
    background: orchid;
}
.cyan{
    background: cyan;
}
/*added rules*/
.content-wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .sidebar-wrapper{
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I've changed my picture because i've made a mistake for the order between orange and purple block. I've updated my picture. Can you take a look ?

Comment: Hey! Ouch, ok its gonna be a bit tricky, but it can be done; I'll update this post as soon as I have a solution, stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), I think the .col-md-8 and .col-md-4 classes will be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Since stack Overflow will not do any project i posted you simple and easy step**

Bootstrap use media-queries
example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
                div {
                    width: 80%
                }
          }
```

this above query works if screen is bellow `500px` div width will be `80%`

try this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browserwindow. When the width of this document is less than 300 pixels, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "lightgreen".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Above example will show when screen size is bellow `600px` page color will change from `lightgreen` to `lightblue`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">orange</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="row">violet row</div>
           <div class="row">light blue</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

I used xs-12  for the mobile. Please post your example code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers.

Here's what i've made with the help of all answers :

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 bg-info">
                <h4>Content 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-warning pull-right">
                <h4>Sidebar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 bg-success pull-left">
                <h4>Content 2</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:purple; color:#fff">Contents box 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" style="background-color:red; color:#fff">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff">Contents box 2</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:purple; color:#fff">Contents box 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" style="background-color:red; color:#fff">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff">Contents box 2</div>    
</div>
```